# How to solve Straight line questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If a line l is passing through the points $(k,2k),(3k,3k)$ and $(3,1)$ and the distance through the origin is

$$a)\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$$     $$b)\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}$$      $$c)\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$$     $$d)\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}$$
Please how to find this type of questions? 
Please explain in brief?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math Stack Exchange! To get the best answers on your skill level and to learn most of it, it is needed to show your attempt. You can edit your post to add this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the line passing through corresponding points then it means slope point taken in order is equal.

Equating slope for point 1, point 2 and point 2 , point 3 gives.

$\frac{3k-2k}{3k-k}=\frac{1-3k}{3-3k}$

Solving it gives $k=\frac{-1}{3}$

Hence slope of line is $\frac{1}{2}$ and passes through point $(3,1)$

Therefore equation of line is

$2y-x+1=0$

It's $\perp$ distance from origin is

$d=\dfrac{|2.0-0+1|}{\sqrt{2^2+1^2}}$